# file upload using php

Tags: php, mysql

i am developing register form using php where i need to upload the file its not uploading

```
$firstname=$_REQUEST['firstname'];
$lastname=$_REQUEST['lastname'];
$username=$_REQUEST['username'];
$password=$_REQUEST['password'];
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];
$Image=basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$Image=str_replace(' ','|',$Image);

if($firstname && $lastname && $username && $email)
{
  require 'dbconnect.php';
  $query="select * from members where email='$email'";
  $result=mysql_query($query);
  $exists=mysql_num_rows($result);
  if($exists>0)
  {
    $message=array("message"=>"email already existed");
    echo json_encode($message);
  }
  else
  {
    if($Image)
    { 
      $Image=date("YmdHis").".jpg";    
      $target_path="userimages/".$Image;
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$target_path);
      $query="INSERT INTO `members` 
        (`username`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `password`, `image`)  VALUES 
        ('$username', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$password',  '$Image')";
    }
    else
    {
      $query="INSERT INTO `members` (`username`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `password`)  VALUES 
       ('$username', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$password')";
    }
    $result=mysql_query($query);
  }
}
```

html code is

```
<html>
<form action="register.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>firstname<input type="text" name="firstname"></div>
<div>lastname<input type="text" name="lastname"></div>
<div>username<input type="text" name="username"></div>
<div>password<input type="text" name="password"></div>
<div>email<input type="text" name="email"></div>
<div>image<input type="file" name="file"></div>
<div><input type="submit" name="submit"></div>
</form>
</html>
```

in this i upload image but its not uploaded to server and also to database in this else condition is exicuted

please help me

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: did you check the value of $_FILES["file"]["error"] to see if it uploaded correctly

Comment: @gunnx:i echo $image it shows nothing and also echo $_FILES["file"]["error"]also it shows nothing

Comment: can you post the html form used

Comment: @gunnx:`<html>
<form action="register.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data>
<div>firstname<input type="text" name="firstname"></div>
<div>lastname<input type="text" name="lastname"></div>
<div>username<input type="text" name="username"></div>
<div>password<input type="text" name="password"></div>
<div>email<input type="text" name="email"></div>
<div>image<input type="file" name="file"></div>
<div><input type="submit" name="submit"></div>
</form>
</html>`

Comment: @Suresh Please update your question to include this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the permissions on the folder you are trying to write to - if the image is not being uploaded and the `move_uploaded_file` fails, then the row won't be inserted into the database at all.

For comparison, here's some code from an app I use to upload a file to the server:

```
if ((($_FILES["avatar"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["avatar"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["avatar"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["avatar"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["avatar"]["size"] < 200000))
{
    if ($_FILES["avatar"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        $error =  "Return Code: " . $_FILES["avatar"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
    else
    {
        $fname = time() . '-' . $formData['username'] .$_FILES["avatar"]["name"];
        $fname = str_replace(" ", "_", $fname);
        if (file_exists("/myserverdir/images/avatars/" . $fname))
        {
            $fname = time() . '-' . $formData['username'] .$_FILES["avatar"]["name"];
            $fname = str_replace(" ", "_", $fname);
        }
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"], "/myserverdir/images/avatars/" . $fname);
    }
}
else if (!file_exists($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name']))
{
    $fname = 'default_avatar.jpg';
}
else
{
    $error = "Invalid file";
}
```

My form looks something like:

```
<form method="post" action="myaction.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="avatar" />
    <input type="text" name="username" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your `<form>` tag has the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute

Comment: In the form code you posted, it looks like you didn't close the quotes around multipart/form-data.

Comment: Never mind, you have updated it now to include the closing quote. What OS are you using on your web server? Can you check the logs for any PHP errors? Or, alternatively, put error_reporting(E_ALL); at the top of your register.php